# When specific string is in certain variable, how to make value in another variable. ( in R )

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, filter

Image down below is the first head(10) of the data frame.

[image]

Here's what I want to do.
If the word "facebook" , "instagram", "youtube" is included in 'source' variable as a 'referral', change referral -> social in 'medium' variable.

But, I need to leave others just as it was such as organic or direct even if they have facebook|instagram|youtube in the string. It needs to be work only referral to social, not direct and organic.

I guess I can use if statement also filter function.., but I'm just stuck here and don't know where to start.. I'd like to know the technique for this.

```
referral2 <- mutate(referral, medium = ifelse( ))
```

Thanks..!

Comment: `library(stringr); referral2 <- mutate(referral, medium = ifelse(str_detect(source, 'facebook|instagram|youtube'), 'social', medium)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of these options `base R` or `dplyr` using `grepl()` to test conditions. You can set a vector for your tags and then with `grepl()` and `paste0()` check the coincidences and assign the value to `medium` as you wish. I have simulated some data. Please next time include a sample of your data and not a screenshot as it is difficult for us to copy the data when it is big. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
set;seed(123)
#Data
df <- data.frame(source=c('facebook','linkedin','Other','Myfacebook',
                          'Myyoutube','instagram','myinstagram'),
                 medium=rep('referral',7),
                 newuser=round(runif(7,1000,24000)),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Vector of keys
vec <- c("facebook" ,"instagram","youtube")
#Replace new variable
df$medium <- ifelse(grepl(paste0(vec,collapse = '|'),df$source,ignore.case = T),'social',df$medium)
#Dplyr
df <- df %>% mutate(medium=ifelse(grepl(paste0(vec,collapse = '|'),source,ignore.case = T),
                            'social',medium))
```

Output:

```
       source   medium newuser
1    facebook   social   16354
2    linkedin referral   18804
3       Other referral   17855
4  Myfacebook   social   12405
5   Myyoutube   social   14625
6   instagram   social   18539
7 myinstagram   social    4299
```

The longest way would be nesting conditionals for each tag like this (it will produce the same output):

```
#Replace new variable2
df$medium <- ifelse(grepl("facebook",df$source,ignore.case = T),
                    "social",ifelse(grepl("instagram",df$source,ignore.case = T),
                                    "social",ifelse(grepl("youtube",df$source,ignore.case = T),"social",df$medium)))
```

But it is better using `grepl()` and `paste0()` from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I like to combine dplyr with the `stringr` package for tasks like this. Does basically the same as Duck's "Dplyr"-Solution:

`df$medium <- if_else(stringr::str_detect(df$source, "facebook|instagram|youtube"), "social", "referral")`

Comment: I have one more question. 

When there are more values than source variable ( ex. referral, organic, direct, etc ), I want to set "facebook|instagram|youtube" as 'social' only in the case when those words are included in medium as a referral, but leave others just as it was.

The picture that I uploaded was just a subset, so I forgot to mention my original purpose..

Thanks.

Comment: So the entire procedure should only replace "referral" with "social" but never replace any other values in `medium`? Should work like this: `df$medium <- if_else(df$medium == "referral" & stringr::str_detect(df$source, "facebook|instagram|youtube"), "social", "referral")`

Comment: That code changes everything into referral... So, referral should be changed to social when values includes "facebook|instagram|youtube", but other values like organic and direct aren't needed to be changed into anything else even if they includes those words.

Comment: Easier explanation will be when medium is referral, if source variable includes facebook|instagram|youtube, change medium variable from 'referral' to 'social'